# How to parse a JSON file like this?

Tags: json, jq, pubchem

I'd like to parse [this JSON file](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/5317139/JSON/).

to get something like this with the 2nd column as Canonical SMILES and 3rd column as Isomeric SMILES.

```
5317139<TAB><TAB>CCCC=C1C2=C(C3C(O3)CC2)C(=O)O1<TAB>CCC/C=C\\1/C2=C(C3C(O3)CC2)C(=O)O1
```

Could anybody show me how to do it in the best way in jq?

Answer (score 0):

The following jq script (run with the -r command-line option) meets the stated requirements, assuming that the occurrence of `<TAB><TAB>` is a typo:

```
def getString($TOCHeading):
  .. | objects | select( .TOCHeading == $TOCHeading)
  | .Information[0].Value.StringWithMarkup[0].String;

.Record
| [.RecordNumber,
   getString("Canonical SMILES"),
   getString("Isomeric SMILES")]
| @tsv
```

This script produces:

```
5317139 CCCC=C1C2=C(C3C(O3)CC2)C(=O)O1  CCC/C=C\\1/C2=C(C3C(O3)CC2)C(=O)O1
```

Comment: Both "StringWithMarkup" are arrays. How to make the code robust in case there are more than one such strings (for example, show an error and return non-zero)?

Comment: The jq solution is already robust in a certain sense. Please clarify the new requirements, or maybe ask a new SO question.